# Best Practices for Creating or Enhancing LightSwitch Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm researching the use of Microsoft LightSwitch as a target for an automated UI/code builder. The application builder might create LightSwitch solutions and projects, and might create or modify existing .lsml files. What are the best practices for doing so? Is LightSwitch markup language documented?

Likely LightSwitch HTML, as opposed to desktop, will be the target but possibly both. LightSwitch is of interest specifically for its cross-device UI capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered in the Microsoft LightSwitch forum:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/0b47f106-f6ba-4246-93ba-1e43dce6bfcb